# AcknowledgingMessageListener syncronicity

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

I'm trying to implement Kafka consumer using `spring-integration-kafka` abstractions. There is a necessity to handle messages synchronously.

Does `org.springframework.integration.kafka.listener.AcknowledgingMessageListener.java` handle messages synchronously?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it doesn't matter which `MessageListener` impl you use. 
The `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` guaranties the Kafka messages order delivery to the listener. From the same `partition`, of course.

If you shift messages from your `MessageListener` to another Thread using for example `ExecutorChannel`, we can't help you to keep order.

From other side you can `acknowledge()` only higher `offset`s, if you handle messages in batches, for example.